# explode two-item-list in array as key=>value

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'd like to explode a multi-line-string like this

```
color:red
material:metal
```

to an array like this

```
$array['color']=red
$array['material']=metal
```

any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you can use a regexp for it, but it's simple enough without the overhead.

```
$data = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $dataString) as $cLine) {
    list ($cKey, $cValue) = explode(':', $cLine, 2);
    $data[$cKey] = $cValue;
}
```

As mentioned in comments, if data is coming from a Windows/DOS environment it may well have CRLF newlines, adding the following line before the `foreach()` would resolve that.

```
$dataString = str_replace("\r", "", $dataString); // remove possible \r characters
```

The alternative with regexp can be quite pleasant using [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/^(.+?):(.+)$/m', $dataString, $matches);
$data = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: Don't forget to at least strip out the possible `"\r"` from `$cValue`.

Comment: @Jon Quite right, amended with that alteration and a regexp version which is quite pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$value = '1|a,2|b,3|c,4|d';
$temp = explode (',',$value);
foreach ($temp as $pair) 
{
    list ($k,$v) = explode ('|',$pair);
    $pairs[$k] = $v;
}

print_r($pairs);
```

Answer (score 1):

explode first on line break. Prolly \n

Then explode each of the resulting array's items on : and set a new array to that key/value.