# How to split values in a array for each item in php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have a simple php question.

I have a value like the following for 2 products.
1 product has options density, flavor and pid
other product has option color and pid

**product 1**

```
density: Low 12mg, flavor: Dekang Dark USA Mix, pid: 165
```

**product 2**

```
color: Silver, pid: 5
```

The above 2 values comes in a single array

```
$items[$i]['options']
```

How can i convert it into an array of the following format...

```
product 1-   density => 'Low 12mg, flavor =>  'Dekang Dark USA Mix', pid => '165'
product 2-    color =>  'Silver', pid => '5'
```

and how to call it in a foreach loop so that i get values separately for 2 products ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming options values are separated by comma:

```
$myArray = explode(',', $items[$i]['options']);
```

Then you can use that array to fill in your object. Full example:

```
$items[0] = array("id" => 1,  
          "options" => 'density: Low 12mg, flavor: Dekang Dark USA Mix, pid: 165');
$items[1] = array("id" => 2,
          "options" => 'color: Silver, pid: 5');

$newItems = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {

    $options = explode(',', $item['options']);

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $values = explode(':', $option);
        $item[trim($values[0])] = trim($values[1]);
    }
    $newItems[] = $item;
}

print_r($newItems);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b4ccc3ee27b53340cabff8d313f4733085e01e2

Comment: I think the OP wants to make the `label:` an associative array of the item pieces. So: `$item['density'] => 'Low 12mg'`.

Comment: @Xabier The above code is not working...I have corrected errors in code above like missing closing bracket etc..

Comment: well, it was just a quick example, you will have to test further, i am writing the full sample and post it soon

Comment: @Xabier This link is of similar type issue. but i am unable to understand it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335963/explode-two-item-list-in-array-as-key-value

Comment: @Xabier I am still getting options as density: Low 12mg, flavor: Dekang Dark USA Mix, pid: 165   I require it like $item['density'] => 'Low 12mg'...for second product options are different color and pid

Comment: just change the options to whatever the options are in your sample, if you check the sandbox example you can see that you get `$item[density] =>  Low 12mg`etc..

Comment: @Xabier How to call individual items like pid, density etc.      Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Dekang 10 [quantity] => 2 [price] => 6.27 [options] => density: Low 12mg, flavor: Dekang Dark, pid: 165 [density] => Low 12mg [ flavor] => Dekang Dark [ pid] => 165 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Dekang 10  [quantity] => 2 [price] => 6.27 [options] => density: Low 12mg, flavor: Dekang Dark, pid: 165 [color] => Silver [ pid] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => 2014 Battery [quantity] => 1 [price] => 23.52 [options] => color: Silver, pid: 5 [color] => Silver [ pid] => 5 ) )

Comment: for example, for the first item you would access density like this: `$newItems[0]['density'];`

Comment: @Xabier The only value i am getting is density...echo $newItems[0]['pid'];
echo $newItems[0]['density'];  pid no value, flavor no value

Comment: and i need to call it in a for loop like echo $newItems[$i]['pid'] $i is my counter

Comment: @user3790186 - To a certain degree, you may need to take code that demonstrates what you need and customize it to your particular code sequence. For instance, wrap it in a function and call the function when you need it.

Comment: But unfortunately the code is displaying only density values....$newItems[$i]['density'];   and no other values like $newItems[$i]['pid'];

Comment: @user3790186, check this code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ca39e43b16428b81e95bc7ffda404283009e3e8

Comment: @user3790186 - Why don't you keep `options` as a sub-array and set each `$newItems` after parsing to it? That way it doesn't overwrite your primary array values? Otherwise you would need to merge the `$newItems` with your current array iteration. The code works as asked though, so you need to think about how to properly integrate it.

Comment: This is just a sample that replies the main question, of course you will have to adapt the code to your final needs. Might you consider overwriting $items elements, use it in a new array as the code provided, or anything else

Comment: @Xabier Thank you. It is working fine. Thank you once again for your patience.